# Does the energy the top load of a spark gap tesla coil discharges have enough amperage to kill you?

Tags: amperage, tesla-coil

I am building a SGTC for my science project, and I thought it would be really cool to be able to hold onto the toroid. But, I don't really want to die. So, I wanted to know how many amps the toroid discharges. Also, if something other than the amps would kill me, could you mention that to?

Comment: https://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/Class/safety.html

Comment: You don't seem to know enough about electricity to be safe while doing your science project, especially one so dangerous with high voltage. I don't think it will kill you, but it will burn you or destroy nerves or similar craziness... You wouldn't want to make a huge ass out of yourself now would you?

Comment: Well.. If you're the one who's going to be building this device; the electrical properties of the circuitry are really dependent on you and your design. Aren't they? Either way, I don't think it's going to be possible for you to handle the live element the way you mentioned. Not without being electrocuted, and/or immolated. At the very least, you'll suffer some serious burns. I can't help but feel like it's probably not the best idea. Good luck though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's potentially suicidal.

Comment: Lmaooo @Andyaka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First , there is no certainty. People have survived contact with tesla coil arcs, and people have died. So, any time you plan to do it, you have to ask yourself 'do I feel lucky?'.

While the current in the arc from a tesla coil topload is low, it can damage you, and it can kill you.

Damage can be caused by RF burns, both on the skin, and in nerves below the skin.

An arc is a continuous channel of hot plasma. This can conduct an arbitrarily large current, if the power supply is capable of supplying it. Unfortunately, tesla coils tend to be operated in the vicinity of mains cables, whether trailing over the floor to reach the coil, or fixed to the walls of a garage. If an arc from the coil hits both you, and a mains connection, the mains supply **is** capable of sending a lethal current through the arc and through you. This is how a performer died on stage demonstrating a coil, taking arcs to the hands. The arc also struck a lighting cable strung above the stage, and he was electrocuted.

Comment: I meant to say this earlier when I upvoted but +1 on the dirty harry quote: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Xjr2hnOHiM